# variable substitution in for each loop- tcl tk programming

Tags: loops, variables, foreach, tcl, substitution

I am trying to find out number of elements failed and the results are to be printed in a .csv file.
this is my code,

```
set n_min_len 10
set n_max_len 50
set n_angle 60
foreach check {"min length" "max length" "angle"} \
        fail {$n_min_len $n_max_len $n_angle} {
   puts $file [format %30s%10s "$check...." "$fail"]
   }
```

I get output as
**min length....$n_min_len**
**max length....$n_max_len** and so on.
Instead I wanted output as
**min length....10**
**max length....50**

can someone help me, how to get this.

thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this part:

```
{$n_min_len $n_max_len $n_angle}
```

The braces block any substitution. Instead you should write

```
"$n_min_len $n_max_len $n_angle"
```

or

```
[list $n_min_len $n_max_len $n_angle]
```